# Printing word table with vertically centered text in cells incorrectly offsetting

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I am printing address labels using Avery's 5160 word template.

In each cell there is address information that spans on 4 lines, vertically centered text.

The first two rows of labels print with a correct vertically centered alignment, but as further down we go, the the first line of text in each cell starts getting closer to the top edge of it's respective label.

I thought that maybe the template had wrong sizes, so I printed the table with inside borders only to see how much of an offset the template had in comparison to the sheet of labels.

To my surprise there is absolutely no offset when I do this.

So I ran the same test again, but this time with the text inside the cells.

The inside borders remain perfectly aligned with the sticker labels, but for some very odd reason the text is the only thing offsetting a bit vertically the further down it goes.

Example:

This is how it appears in word
[image]

And this is an *exact representation* of what it looks like when I print the above
[image]

Notice how the text is going up a big the further down the row count is, yet the cell borders are still perfectly matching each labels' edges.

I also tried making the content of each cell a 4 row table with each text inside each row, and the result is exactly the same; the entire 4 row table and its text are shifting up the further down it goes.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's not completely clear when the issue happens: is it already visible in Word? Does it appear if you print your label to pdf? Only on paper after printing?

Comment: I explained that the issue happens on the printed paper only.

Comment: Seems to be a printer /driver issue. Do you have access to another printer to try it? If you convert to pdf first, do you have the same issue?

Comment: No, if I convert to PDF it prints perfectly, same thing if I convert it to an image using Photoshop. Don't have another printer at hand that I can test it out unfortunately, but I appreciate the suggestion.